# Finding the eigenpairs of an atypical differential operator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I came across a problem that asked me to find the eigenpairs of the operator $M : C^2_D[0, \ell] \to C[0, \ell]$ defined by
$$
My = -c\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+dy,\ \ \ c,d > 0
$$
subject to Dirichlet boundary conditions $y(0) = 0, y(\ell) = 0$. So right away I attempted to solve
$$
-c\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+dy = \lambda y
$$
This differential equation has the characteristic polynomial
$$
-cr^2 + d - \lambda
$$
with roots $r = \pm \sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}$. So I plug them into my general solution:
$$
y(x) = Ae^{\sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}x} + Be^{-\sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}x}
$$
(Note: the $x$ is outside the sqrt)

Using the first boundary condition $y(0) = 0$, I see that $B = -A$. So I get the function
$$
y(x) = Ae^{\sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}x} - Ae^{-\sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}x}.
$$
Using the 2nd boundary condition I get
$$
y(\ell) = Ae^{\sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}\ell} - Ae^{-\sqrt{(d-\lambda)/c}\ell} = 0
$$
(Note: the $\ell$ is outside the sqrt)

This equation can hold only if $\lambda = d$, but if $\lambda = d$ then if I were to plug $\lambda$ back into $y(x)$ then I would get the zero function...
$$
y(x) = Ae^{\sqrt{(d-d)/c}x} - Ae^{-\sqrt{(d-d)/c}x}
$$
$$
y(x) = A - A = 0
$$
and the eigenfunction cannot be the zero function. Should I use a different method for finding the eigenvalues of $M$? Am I missing something basic in finding the eigenvalues?

Comment: This is not atypical, up to scaling and shift of eigenvalues this is just the negative second derivative. The square roots are imaginary numbers, so it is more convenient to use trigonometric functions instead of exponentials, see [Example 1 here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/BVPEvals.aspx).

Comment: @Conifold I know it's more convenient to use trigonometric functions instead, but how do you know the square roots are imaginary if $\lambda$ is unknown?

Comment: Because when they are not the boundary conditions can not be satisfied by non-zero functions, as you yourself computed.

Comment: @Conifold so we would say $\lambda$ must be greater than $d$ and proceed with the complex root method to solve the ODE?

Comment: If you are doing a complete solution you may only assume that $λ$ is a complex number, show that there are no non-zero solutions for $y$ unless $(d−λ)/c$ is negative, and then note that purely imaginary exponentials can be rewritten as trig functions by the Euler's formula and proceed with finding them.